# Coupling asynchronous scripts

Tags: javascript

Please help me to solve the problem with detecting when the asynchronous script is loaded. Actually I have a live chat button on my website that loads asynchronously, the script of this widget is obuscated. I need to set an eventlistener on the chat button after this script loads. Window.onload triggers before chat button appears. Please advise.

Code:

```
_shcp = [];
_shcp.push({
    widget_id: xxxxxx,
    widget: "Chat",
    side: "left",
    position: "center",
    template: "orange",
    title: "Live help",
    text_layout: "trans",
    track: 1
});
(function () {
    var hcc = document.createElement("script");
    hcc.type = "text/javascript";
    hcc.async = true;
    hcc.src = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https" : "http") + "://widget.siteheart.com/apps/js/sh.js";
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(hcc, s.nextSibling);
})();
```

Comment: show us the html/javascript code that loads the chat button.

Comment: Can you add a line to the bottom of the chat script that calls some function in your client code?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript"> _shcp = []; _shcp.push({widget_id : xxxxxx, widget : "Chat", side : "left", position : "center", template : "orange", title : "Live help", text_layout : "trans"    , track : 1 }); (function() { var hcc = document.createElement("script"); hcc.type = "text/javascript"; hcc.async = true; hcc.src = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https" : "http")+"://widget.siteheart.com/apps/js/sh.js"; var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(hcc, s.nextSibling);})();</script>

Comment: tjameson, Yes< I can, but it executes before script loads.

Comment: As you probably noticed, code in comments is very hard to read. You can *edit* your question, and update it with relevant information (like properly formatted code), just like I did now.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is if your chat button has an API that you can attach a callback to when it loads. This is how most other libraries like google maps, YUI and jQuery handles dynamic loading of elements.

But if that is not available, your next best bet is to poll for the existence of the element:

```
setTimeout(function checkChatButton (){
    var button = document.getElementById(chat_button_id);
    if (button) {
        /* Button is loaded!
         *
         * Do what you need to do here
         */
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(checkChatButton,500);
    }
},500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of the bottom block, the script-loading block, add a listener to the script.

```
hcc.onload = function () {
    var button = document.getElementById("the_button");
    button.onclick = function () { doStuff(); };
};
```

Set the `.onload` ***before*** the file gets appended to the DOM.
The safe way would be to put it in the same place you'd set your listener for an AJAX call, or an Image load (before the `src` is set).
If you care to remember it, scripts don't actually start loading until after you add them to the page, while images load as soon as you set the `.src` -- setting your listeners before setting sources, every time, prevents you from having to remember this.

There are nicer, more DOM-3.0 ways of doing this, but that's nice and simple.

If you need to support IE7 or less, you need to listen for `.onreadystatechange` instead:

```
hcc.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (hcc.readyState === "loaded" || hcc.readyState === "complete") {
        var button = document.getElementById("the_button");
        button.onclick = function () { doStuff(); };
    }
}
```

It's a little ugly to have to put them both together on the page, but it's a dead-simple fix to know when your script has loaded and finished running.

Comment: I`ve added `hcc.onload = function ()` before the `hcc.src =...` in the bottom block and it comes with: `Cannot set property 'onclick' of null`. It`s executing too early.

Comment: Okay, then if your script makes another a sync call to another script, your only real option is to set a timer and hope. It's an ugly way to do it, but it will work -- if the script you were loading there did all of the work, the callback method should have worked.  Glad you got it running.